# AES 128 Decryption: First char of CryptoJS.enc.Latin1 is malformed

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

I have a string which is encoded and need to decrypt it. I have used the Crypto JS and after certain research, I could reach to below solution.

```js
data = "+JdTb5BOloxaBHQlTw6NPLNV9lZix1OwhR3HF3IRtu2pdg/TLkrTw6Xu4JpKFlxE+zgOZavj0UynSZ+ojxmDXRbUlfyOc4YAncJVMXr28/AtfxZkNQoHbPIo7WxcSdidNE2k+DHZFcNNKOzYnvL1oDN4ezecs8Vo7K6vC5ZFLPUylXsi5sPsGye+TBbauPX+/wXa3hWUJVMNk6HUghW7l4N5Ei7HnrxLkFSFnz+9YUKYbFMEgV6wd9debHrpyytVhA3x2+Eyn5KnQ7iNJKQsNw==";
key = "062ec23950a55b9f8b21b0f9d45ca853";

// Decode the base64 data so we can separate iv and crypt text.
var rawData = atob(data);
var iv = rawData.substring(0,32);
var crypttext = rawData.substring(32);

// Decrypt...
var plaintextArray = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
  { ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(crypttext) },
  CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key),
  { iv: CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(iv) }
);

var test = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.stringify(plaintextArray);
console.log(test.toString())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/aes.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

The output of the above is

```
8«ÊWÒÏ¬R¶jÛWY#ESPONSE_TEXT>
   <RESULT>OK</RESULT>
   <RESULT_CODE>-1</RESULT_CODE>
   <TERMINATION_STATUS>SUCCESS</TERMINATION_STATUS>
   <COUNTER>2</COUNTER>
   </RESPONSE>
```

Instead of

```
   <RESPONSE_TEXT>
   <RESULT>OK</RESULT>
   <RESULT_CODE>-1</RESULT_CODE>
   <TERMINATION_STATUS>SUCCESS</TERMINATION_STATUS>
   <COUNTER>2</COUNTER>
   </RESPONSE>
```

I am not able to find why `8«ÊWÒÏ¬R¶jÛWY` is been coming to the result. Kindly help to find the missing thread.

Comment: my best guess would be: the IV is wrong ... what happens if you don't pass in CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(iv) but... just iv ?

Comment: That was exactly I was trying but could not work.

Comment: looks like the IV was already garbage when you got it

Comment: This is classic symptoms of wrong IV

Comment: Actually, you assume to much of the encrypted data to be IV, making you start decrypting on the wrong block, this makes the first block you decrypt seem corrupted .. see answer

Comment: The limitation is, I can not get the IV used for encryption. I am trying to pair a device which has generated the encrypted string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use - CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8) to generate iv

```js
data = "+JdTb5BOloxaBHQlTw6NPH2KFaA1mUL2vEuOqHmteozJutLfH1fQrDn+OE8Y1LgoFNqTjpuELCLB1noWbQ9Dz2g6NcD2vPAd4okiYArXnz+YKhVaGcqw+FTThjTWadMD/KvpzZ7SlxBh7HpCbZ/KMmxsOOnuk2F8pVEV3pkJMUgxV36c/iN9C+aRHPt95XRKzfU5ISaoBIq+/9K4WzW6i8yI8r6sdyRDoRc2q/EXuvX5666vdP1yojm2yhaL+1EwgkkYRn+GLyYuzFN1yCi+OA==";
key = "062ec23950a55b9f8b21b0f9d45ca853";

// Decode the base64 data so we can separate iv and crypt text.
var rawData = atob(data);
var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);
var crypttext = rawData;


// Decrypt...
var plaintextArray = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
  { 
   ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(crypttext)
  },
  CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key),
  { 
    iv: CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(iv),
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
  }
);

var decrypted = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.stringify(plaintextArray);
console.log(decrypted);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/guptasanchit90dev/p00fhmp4/

Comment: maybe not a wise idea to decrypt with a random IV instead of the original ... will work in ~ 1 out of 2^128 cases ;)

Comment: Why would you randomly generate an IV and then use that for decryption...?

Comment: Don't generate a random IV in decrypt - you use the one generated when encrypting.